# Echoing the selected date in a dropdown list

Tags: php

Ok i have this code to echo the if the values are selected how can i use this for a date dropdown list without creating a variable for each day?

```
if ($st_title[$i] == 'Mr') {
    $mr_select='selected="selected"';
    $mrs_select='';
    $ms_select='';  
} else if ($st_title[$i]=='Mrs') {
    $mr_select='';
    $mrs_select='selected="selected"';
    $ms_select='';  
} else {
    $mr_select='';
    $mrs_select='';
    $ms_select='selected="selected"';
}
```

I figured it out and just for reference here's what I came up with:

```
for ($x=0; $x<=31; $x++){
$dobd[$x]='';
  if ($x ==$st_dobd){
      $dobd[$x]='selected="selected"';
      }else{
          $dobd[$x]='';
          }
}
for ($x=0; $x<=12; $x++){
$dobm[$x]='';
  if ($x ==$st_dobm){
      $dobm[$x]='selected="selected"';
      }else{
          $dobm[$x]='';
          }
}
for ($x=2000; $x>=1970; $x--){
$doby[$x]='';
  if ($x ==$st_doby){
      $doby[$x]='selected="selected"';
      }else{
          $doby[$x]='';
          }
}




                }
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code? I don't see how it relates to your (not a) question.

Comment: Ok this was a lazy question, anyway I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array with your dates and generate drop-down by this array, keys may be days (dates)  and values 0 or 1 if selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make '\' symbol before this symbol '"'